# How a HTTP server respondes to a client's request

Tags: java, android

could you please give me a sample code on how an Http Server(Java) receives the request of a client(android)? I mean the client sends the request via Httppost, how the server takes the content of these requests in order to see the context and reply? I am trying to built a chat application.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should try to learn about creating web application in Java and run it under a servlet container or RESTlet. There are a lot of tutorial on the web, and it takes a lot of learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server-side of HTTP is *usually* implemented using the protocol stack provided by a web container.  You would then implement your application's server-side as servlets.  There are numerous tutorials on this.

If that's the way you want to proceed, look at one of the standard web containers; e.g. Tomcat, Jetty, Glassfish, etc.  The source code for all of these is available for you to browse, though I should warn you that they are all complicated under the hood.

Assuming that your HTTP service is going to be delivering JSON or XML (rather than HTML) to clients, you may want to look into using a RESTful framework.

Comment: I was thinking about RESTful and now I will try it. Thank you for your answers and your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ServerSocket.  Keep in mind that accept() blocks and, as you will probably run it in a service, you will want to time it out and check for the completion of the service.  That should probably run in its own thread as should the responders to requests.

From there, you can open input and output streams to receive the request and write the response.  There are any number of packages that can help you with the interaction, or you can roll your own, but it doesn't seem like you've done a lot of homework. Perhaps some searching, reading, and more specific questions would more you along more quickly.

Comment: I have already implement such an example and it works! I am looking for an answer for not using sockets. Is it possible?

Comment: My code code in the client looks like this: HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:5432");
        Log.v(TAG, "something");   
        List< BasicNameValuePair > nvps = new ArrayList< BasicNameValuePair >();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username1));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password1));   try { UrlEncodedFormEntity p_entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);  httppost.setEntity(p_entity);
              HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost); HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

Comment: @Earl, because writing your own protocal is a waste of time when clients sends the message using http standard.

Comment: Wouldn't it better to use just HTTP without sockets? I am a newbie and i am just seeking for an answer. I have read a lot these days(regarding this issue) and maybe there are some benefits if not using sockets, such as the communication will be more direct and no code is needed to close the connection. I was also trying to find the answer about how the server accepts and replies to a request from a client with the above code. I am trying to implement a chat application as I already referred. Please, i would like to hear your opinion. Really thank you!

Comment: Thank you gigadot, it is also a really important reason! :)

Comment: @gigadot Sockets is under there no matter what you do. As I already said, there are packages to abstract away the protocol details.  Bottom line: You will have HTTP without Sockets -- it's a matter of whether you deal with them directly or indirectly.

Comment: @Earl, I am not arguing that HTTP doesn't use socket. I just said that it is a waste of time to implement what you can do with HTTP from socket directly like what you suggested.